# L298 with stepper.h disable break

Tags: stepper, l298n

I try to control a Stepper motor with an arduino and a L298. I use the library stepper.h and it works well but i have a problem : the L298 become very hot. So i want to disable the break (the thing that we can't turn the motor by hand), but i don't know how to do this.
Do you have an idea ?
My code is simple :

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

void setup() {
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(60);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // step one revolution  in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
  delay(500);

  // step one revolution in the other direction:
  Serial.println("counterclockwise");
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
  delay(500);
}
```

I took it from here : https://coeleveld.com/arduino-stepper-l298n/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no facility in the stepper library to do what you want - however the stepper library just sequences IO pins in the right order.

There's nothing to stop you just placing those same IO pins in a different state - the library won't care.

```
void sleepStepper() {
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
}
```

That will effectively set every port of the L298 LOW, which is equivalent to "brake" mode on a normal DC motor, or "not actively driving" on a stepper (not perfect freewheel, there is still some flyback braking).

Another option is to connect the EN pin(s) of your L298 chip to a GPIO and use that to turn the whole system on and off. That will disconnect the drivers from the motor and give you even less movement resistance than the "all low" method above.

Comment: Oh ! I thought that the library will block the pins ! Thank you.

Comment: @LelaidierLucas Nah - it just performs a sequence of `digitalWrite()` calls.